# How to get Oauth Token from Spotify

Tags: python, spotify

Currently I'm trying to learn how to add the liked youtube videos into a Spotify playlist using python and I'm learning from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J_qcttfnJA&t=300s

In 2:18 of the video, she mentions to add the userID and oauth token from spotify using spotify web API website https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/

However, I'm unable to find where is the OAUTH token.

The programmer also uploaded an image of where she got her token from but I can't seem to find it: https://github.com/TheComeUpCode/SpotifyGeneratePlaylist/blob/master/images/spotify_token.png

Answer (score 7):

Steps below to get the auth token:

1. Navigate to the spotify developers documentation page:
   https://developer.spotify.com/
2. On the top, Select on the console
   tab.
3. From left hand side select on "tracks" and then "get a track",
   this should take you to page:
   https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-track/
4. Now you should can
   see a "get token" button and "try it" button.
5. Click on "Get Token"
   and you should get the OAuth Token.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/ and create an spotify developer account. Then create an app and then you would get the client_id there.

Well, after that, the process to get the oauth token which is required for every call made to spoify api is quite tedious and it is user per basis. And user id is just the id of user who logged in to your app and let your app use spotify account details.

For oAuth token through your app UI - follow this --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZvGnvOShStI

**THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED FOR TIME BEING**  --> If you want to authenticate yourself and get oAuth token go there --> https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-playlists/ and click get token.

Comment: thanks, I got that however I'm unable to get the Oauth Token!